# AWS: Strange behavior from Route 53 and S3 when trying to host static page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53, registrar

Having some problems to get AWS Route 53 to work properly with a static page I host on S3. Get some very strange behavior with traffic being directed to my registrars landing page that I don't understand.

**What I have done so far:**

- Registered a domain with registrar (Gandi), let us call it example.io
- Created a S3 bucket called example.io
- In S3 bucket: Updated bucket permissions to allow all externals access to bucket content (standard AWS bucket policy)
- In S3 bucket: Enabled website hosting and reference index.html
- In S3 bucket: Uploaded static webpage index.html
- Created Route 53 Hosted Zone called example.io
- In Hosted Zone: Created a new record set (type A, alias target is my S3 bucket named example.io)
- Updated name servers on registrar (Gandi) hompage with those in provided in NS record set created in Hosting zone in Route 53
- Verified through tracking service (http://www.simpledns.com/lookup-dg.aspx) that AWS name servers are used when calling example.io

**Effect:**

- When I call example.io from browser I get redirected to Gandi landing page
- When I call S3 bucket endpoint from browser  (example.io.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com) I get redirected to Gandi landing page
- When I call index.html endpoint in S3 bucket from browser (https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/example.io/index.html) my static page load correctly

Greatly appreciate any help on how to get example.io calls to be routed to my static landing page hosted on S3. Quite new to the forum so please excuse any beginner errors!

Regards Adam

Comment: you should give your domain not just an example- the problem is likely in the nameserver configuration.

Comment: Gandi's default name servers hand out a ttl of several hours. Your issue should remedy itself any time now.

Comment: Thanks Michael! Absolutely correct, after a couple of hours it started working. Thanks for the help!